# Disable security restrictions of IE in .net application

Tags: .net, security

I am having an issue with using fileupload control because I am trying to hide the control always and when going through the exception onjavascript it read as"Access is denied" ..

Doing research yielded out because of security issue IE freaks out to post the file .

Is there a way to say something in the response headers while rendering the page to ignore all the security that comes with IE browsers

Example: Adding an attibute in the code to say IE to bipass the security issue and say that is oaky.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  It would be a huge security flaw/risk to allow an incoming response to alter security settings on the client browser.
And if you are trying to always hide the control, why even have it on the page?

Comment: The reason for hiding the control is I want the file upload control to be opened when we click on a link button so that the user does not see the actual control.